# Как поставить отрицание в While?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На вход этой программы поступает строка, начинающаяся с символа «>», содержащая 20 цифр 1, 15 цифр 2, 40 цифр 3 и оканчивающаяся символом «<». Определите, в каком порядке должны располагаться цифры во входной строке, чтобы сумма цифр, получившаяся в результате выполнения программы, была максимально возможной. В ответе запишите эту максимально возможную сумму. Так, например, если результат работы программы представлял бы собой строку, состоящую из 50 цифр 4, то верным ответом было бы число 200.

Я решил просто проверить все значения, что возможно и написал такой код, но понятия не имею, как поставить отрицание в While.

```
x = "<" + "1" * 20 + "2" * 15 + "3" * 40 + ">"
while not("><") in x:
    x = x.replace(">1","3>",1)
    x = x.replace( ">2", "2>",1)
    x = x.replace(">3","1>",1)
    x = x.replace("3<", "<1",1)
    x = x.replace("2<", "<3",1)
    x = x.replace("1<","<2",1)
x = x.replace("<","")
x = x.replace(">","")
print(sum(map(int,x)))
```

С таким кодом происходит просто бесконечный цикл.

Comment: Ответ на конкретный вопрос - `while "><" not in x:`  Но это не решает проблему `все значения, что возможно`. И перебор всех перестановок не позволит найти решение за разумное время

Comment: У меня была идея решения с помощью списков, но дальше идей не вышло, я понятия не имею, как перебирать места символов в строке

Comment: Модуль itertools поможет сгенерировать перестановки. Но их слишком дофига - 9 557 458 653 977 625 262 226 768 859 600...

Comment: Почему так много? Вам надо перебирать не все цифры, а только порядок 1,2,3. То есть "1" * 20 + "3" * 40 + "2" * 15 и т.д.

Comment: Ну хорошо, если так. Тогда вручную запишите 6 возможных вариантов, да и всё

Comment: Да, вручную я уже перебрал всё возможное. А как сделать, чтобы этим занимался код, а не я это задача :D

Comment: Модуль itertools

Comment: `while not("><") in x:` - скобки тут лишние, но сама конструкция `not y in x` работает точно так же, как `y not in x`, с этим проблем нет на самом деле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По условию у вас первый и последний символы должны быть ">" и "<", у вас наоборот.

И если я все правильно понял, то вот решение:

```
x = ">" + "1" * 20 + "2" * 15 + "3" * 40 + "<"

while '><' not in x:
    x = x.replace('>1', '3>', 1)
    x = x.replace('>2', '2>', 1)
    x = x.replace('>3', '1>', 1)
    x = x.replace('3<', '<1', 1)
    x = x.replace('2<', '<3', 1)
    x = x.replace('1<', '<2', 1)

print(sum(map(int, x.replace('><', ''))))
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @tonysdev возможно вы знаете, как возможно реализовать перебор всех подстановок в этом задании, у меня была идея через списки, но она вышла провалом.